# qudits vs bipartite system states

Tags: quantum-state, hilbert-space

Suppose we have a bipartite system of two qubits. It will form a 4d hilbert space.

Also, suppose I have just one quantum system and it is a 4-level system. It will also form a 4d Hilbert space.

What are the differences and similarities between such states. Can we effectively interchange their meaning ?

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate of https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17183/is-it-possible-to-perform-quantum-computation-between-different-hilbert-spaces

Comment: Also potentially related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14049/can-a-single-qutrit-in-superposition-be-considered-entangled